# Delphi Rio after patching not starting

Tags: delphi, installation

I just did a complete system rebuild (format C drive and go from there)... Win 10 Pro 64 bit.  I reinstalled Delphi Rio, the INITIAL release (6.7GB).... Delphi started up fine.  I had previously downloaded Delphi Rio Patch 2, (7.3GB), so I unzipped it, and ran setup.  It automatically chose the middle option (Modify), so I left it at that... and installed.  It appeared to run fine.  After completion, I noticed that it had removed the Delphi icon I created on my desktop, and that the links in my start menu for Delphi no longer work...  I did not investigate a whole lot, as I had a patch 3 (7.9GB) to install as well.  I unzipped, ran setup, and again Modify was the default option, so I ran with that... no errors.  When completed, I tried to run Delphi.  I have what I think is the appropriate directory structure (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin) with 298 files in the bin directory, however bds.exe is NOT one of the files.  Any idea what is going on?

The only possibility I can think of is that I have let my subscription expire....  and I am not entitled to the patches, yet the Embarcadero support system let me download them.  Could this be the explanation?

Comment: Nope. Something broke while running the patch or update, and you possibly made it worse by not checking between them to make sure things still worked before proceeding. I'd suggest you just uninstall Delphi entirely and start over. When the IDE installs, run it to make sure it works. Then apply the first of the updates and run the IDE again. If that works, move to the next update. It' seldom a good idea to just assume that things worked when doing multiple updates. Your first indication of a problem was the desktop icon disappearing; at that point you should have stopped to check thngs.

Comment: And no, EMBT does not stop you from using your current copy when your subscription expires. They don't work like ransomware ("Keep renewing or we'll screw you over by breaking your system").. They just stop allowing you to download new releases or receiving some support services.

Comment: I'm not sure why at the point you *noticed that it had removed the Delphi icon* and *the links in my start menu for Delphi no longer worked* you didn't know something serious was wrong and you kept going. I'm also not sure why when you've just done a new install of Delphi on a newly initialized drive, you would choose *Modify* - it couldn't possibly need a modify when it's a new install.

Comment: @ken-white  - I installed the initial release. It was a full install. I started it up... it ran fine. At this point, I did a full system backup...I then went to install the 2nd file. This is where I had 3 options... I forget the exact text of the first option, but it was something like upgrade license and new features, option2 was modify (which was automatically selected), and option 3 was remove. So what do I do? If I UNINSTALL, does this decrement the installation counter? Are the installs cumulative? For example, can I uninstall and then just install the 3rd ISO file? (10.3.3 ISO)

Comment: The documentation for the ISOs usually tell you whether they include patches or not. I'm not sure, because I'm on Sydney now and haven't updated Rio in a while. I do know that once you had your first indication of a problem you should have stopped and resolved that issue, and that the only way I see to go forward is a total uninstall (including deleting registry entries) and starting over as I described before.

Comment: Why have you skipped Update 1? That might have broken the update process as Update 2 expected that Update 1 was already installed. Also why don't you use Delphi 10.3.3 ISO which allows you to install Delphi 10.3.3 straight away not needing to go though all three patches?

Answer (score 0):

Updating a certain Delphi version is usually done like this:

1. Download new ISO file or web installer
2. Uninstall the Delphi version you want to update and keep the registry settings (you are asked about this during the process)
3. Run setup from downloaded ISO or web installer

Your approach of installing the newer version on top of the older one is clearly the wrong way.
This is also explained in the install instructions (readme file) that comes with every ISO or web installer.